# What do the error code values for RunWait() mean?

Tags: windows, autoit

Documentation for [`RunWait()`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/RunWait.htm) lacks description of returned error codes.

What do the different error code values mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because these codes appear as a result of the programs you run with `RunWait`, not to this AutoIT function.

Generic success code is zero, and any non-zero value could mean absolutely anything, and the only way to know what happened is to study this exact app or console command output.

Comment: If its your own app the return code is one you would specify.  See the Exit() command's argument.